# Cannot reuse an endpoint after NetMQ socket disposal

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, zeromq, netmq

In my application I am creating and disposing NetMQ sockets. I have noticed that I cannot bind to an endpoint for some time after the disposal of the previous socket bound to that endpoint. A minimal example:

```
const string endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:1234";

using (var publisher = new PublisherSocket())
    publisher.Bind(endpoint);

using (var publisher = new PublisherSocket())
    publisher.Bind(endpoint); //throws a NetMQException: "Unknown error (0xffffffff)"
```

The `Linger` option is set to 0, but I still have to wait (up to several seconds in my experiments) before the second bind.

I could add a `Thread.Sleep` or some other delaying instruction, but this is neither robust nor elegant.

Is this a bug? If not, what is the proper way of making sure that I can already bind to an endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug,  the dispose of a socket is async and happen in a background thread.  You can try and call Unbind before the dispose,  it might be faster.